# Maven: zip resources and save into specific folder

Tags: java, maven, zip, maven-assembly-plugin

For a project I need to zip a number of resource files and put this archive inside the project source (src/main/resources). The idea is that this archive then ends up in the EAR and goes to the deployment server, where it is picked up by a script for further processing. Convoluted, I know, but those are the constraints we are working with.

I've created an Assembly plugin configuration file that creates the zip, but this zip is placed by default in a target/ folder.

The assembly plugin has an outputDirectory option, but this only changes the filestructure of the *contents* of the zip, not the location where the zip is saved.

Is there a way to specify where the assembly plugin saves the created zip? Or is there a better way altogether to zip resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two `outputDirectory` configuration, [one](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#binaries) represents the file path inside your assembled package, 
[another one](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly-mojo.html#outputDirectory) represents directory where your assembled package would be output

[you are looking for second one](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly-mojo.html#outputDirectory)

Comment: The link "you are looking for second one" is not working .

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following code in pom.xml , provide the path in outputDirectory tag  :

```
     <execution>
             <id>assembly-execution</id> 
            <phase>package</phase> 
            <goals>
            <goal>single</goal> 
            </goals>
            <configuration>
            <finalName>zipFileName</finalName>
            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            <descriptors>
                <descriptor>${project.basedir}/zip.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
 <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>             
     </execution>
```